# React "createPortal" outside of "return()"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm in a situation where I want to add a `div` inside a pre-existing `div` with a known `id` and I want to do all of this when a button is clicked. I read [the documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal) and as far as I'm able to understand I have to call the `createPortal()` somewhere in the `return()` of the component otherwise react is not able to render the new content.

There is a simplified example of what I'd like to achieve:

```
const spawnDiv = content => createPortal(content, document.getElementById("spawn-here"));

const handleClick = () => {
    if (conditionIsMet) {
        spawnDiv(<h1>I'm a spawned heading</h1>);
    }
};
```

And this of course doesn't work. So, is there a way to achieve this without calling `createPortal()` in the `return()` of the component thus increasing code complexity and readability? Thx in advance!

Comment: Where is `handleClick` called? You still need to *render* the portal - `createPortal` returns an element that you need to make part of the JSX tree.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, thanks, the answer below solved my problem. I'm new to react so I kinda understood that from the docs, but I was curious if there was a way to do it more directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, is there a way to achieve this without calling createPortal() in the return

No, you'll need to call createPortal as part of rendering, and then return it. You can call it conditionally if you like, based on some state, so that's probably what you want to do here:

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [showHeading, setShowHeading] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (conditionIsMet) {
      setShowHeading(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      This text is *not* part of the portal
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button>
      {showHeading && createPortal(
        <h1>I'm a spawned heading</h1>, 
        document.getElementById("spawn-here")
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

If a boolean is not enough of a state to calculate what you want to show in the portal, you can change it to a more complex state.

Comment: Mmmmm, ok. I'm quite new to React so sometimes I don't understand these mechanics... Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Since we're here, I'll ask for another thing: actually I have to spawn different subdivs based on some conditions. I noticed that this code just append a child to the div I pass. How can I remove all children of "spawn-here" `div` and spawn a new one?

Comment: Is this the only component making changes to spawn-here? If so, have a state which describes all the stuff you want to put in spawn-here. An array is a natural state for that. Then to clear spawn-here, empty out the array. If multiple components are all putting things in spawn-here, and you need to be able to have them coordinate, then i recommend you make a new component who's sole purpose is to manage the contents of spawn-here, and have all the others tell it what they want done.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up changing a bit the logic for compatibility issues with a non-react library I'm using but I managed to solve the issues. Thanks again for the help!